# Search all identifiers in a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

In my postgres logs, I'm getting a notification every few seconds saying "sql_error_code = 42622". [Apparently, this means an identifier is too long.](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/8f87c65a0a-postgresqls-max-identifier-length-is-63-bytes) The identifier is unfamiliar to me, so I'm trying to figure out where it's coming from. To track this down, I'd like to look for any identifier in the database (the query doesn't need to have a where clause).

I believe that means I need a query to see every:

1. Schema name
2. Tablename
3. Column name
4. Index name
5. Foreign key name
6. *And anything else I could be missing that could be considered an identifier.*

I could pull this off by using the information_schema to make a massive, multi-query union to get this information, but it would take a lot of time to write that. Is there a faster way to search any identifier?

Comment: The `information_schema` might not expose everything. Better browse through [`pg_catalog`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html). But if the identifier is too long or not accepted for other reasons, there won't be any object with it. It cannot be created with that identifier.

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong place. I would guess some query uses an identifier that is longer than allowed and gets truncated. There can be no identifier in the system that is longer than allowed.

Comment: Best bet is to tail the Postgres log and see what actually shows up when the error is thrown.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Does looking at the Heroku logs for the database count? That's what I looked at ask this question. The identifier is foreign to me, so I don't know where it's coming from and it doesn't give me any other information but the name of the identifier.

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL log for the statement that causes the error and add it to the question.

Comment: As @LaurenzAlbe said you will need to find where the Postgres logs are written in Heroku and look at the statement that throws that error.